# Drawing Overlapping Images in Libgdx with a Table

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Basically, I'm trying to draw an empty health bar as an image, and then the actual health bar on top of it as another image so that I can just shorten the actual health bar when I need to update it. This is what I have so far:

```
    TextureAtlas HUDatlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/ui/HUDPack/textures.pack"));

    emptyPlayerHealthBar = new Image(HUDatlas.findRegion("empty-health-bar"));
    playerHealthBar = new Image(HUDatlas.findRegion("health-bar"));

    //Creating the table
    table = new Table(skin);
    table.debug();
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 50);
    table.left();
    table.top();
    table.add(playerHealthBar);
    table.add(emptyPlayerHealthBar);
    stage.addActor(table);
```

But this draws them side-by-side. How do I draw it so that the images are overlapping (empty-health-bar on the bottom and health-bar on top)?

Comment: Do you need to use table for it? If you need to try using a group, add the empty and the normal helth bar to it and add the group to the table

Comment: Should i add it as an answer?

Comment: @Springrbua that is a great answer that solved my problem, thanks

Comment: @Kintaro i am glad that i could help (:

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to place a diamond over a box:

```
Image boxImage = new Image(Assets.instance.gifts.box);
Image diamondImage = new Image(Assets.instance.gifts.diamond);
Stack diamondBox = new Stack();
diamondBox.addActor(boxImage);
diamondBox.addActor(diamondImage);
tbl.add(diamondBox).width(20).height(20);
tbl.row();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use Scene2D's `WidgetGroup` (or, if you're not using layout managers, e.g. `Table`, `Group`) for that, e.g.

TextureAtlas HUDatlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/ui/HUDPack/textures.pack"));

```
emptyPlayerHealthBar = new Image(HUDatlas.findRegion("empty-health-bar"));
playerHealthBar = new Image(HUDatlas.findRegion("health-bar"));

// creating the group
WidgetGroup group = new WidgetGroup();
group.addActor(playerHealthBar);
group.addActor(emptyPlayerHealthBar);

// creating the table
table = new Table(skin);
table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 50);
table.debug().left().top().add(group);

stage.addActor(table);
```

Note that you can offset those bars simply by using `.setPosition()` on them, as usual with libGDX's 2.5D objects. Also, you can make your libGDX code more concise by using method chaining, although that's mostly a matter of style.